# Can you show a flash message conditionally on what happened inside a yield block in an around_action filter?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

I think I have an understanding of how an `around_action` works, basically performing what is before the `yield` as a `before_action` and what happens after the `yield` as an `after_action`.

I would like to know how to effectively handle errors and feedback given to the user if something wrong happens along the way, since `yield` runs all the code in the block (in this exampe, the `index` action of a controller) no matter what.

How can I display flash messages conditionally of wether an error was raised or if a rescue from error was performed or not?

**Problem:** A `flash[:success]` is rendered even when a `rescue` from error is performed (misleading).

*controller:*

```
class ReportsController
  around_action :wrap_in_transaction, only: %i(index)
  rescue_from FileExportError, with: :file_export_error

  def index
    @tickets = Ticket.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xlsx do
        response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=report"
      end
    end
    flash[:success] = "Success"
    update_tickets(@tickets) # rolls back if a rescue happens
    end
  end

  private

  def wrap_in_transaction
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      yield
    rescue FileExportError
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  end

  def file_export_error
    flash[:danger] = t(".file_export_error")

    redirect_to reports_path
  end

  def update_tickets(tickets)
    tickets.each do |ticket|
      ticket.update(status: "unpaid")
    end
  end
end
```

*.xls.erb raise error if corrupted data trying to build file:*

```
@tickets.each do |ticket|
  if ticket.some_data.nil?
        raise FileExportError
  end
  sheet.add_row [ticket.user.full_name,
                 ticket.user.phone,
                 ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

(Disregard my prev answer, I was skimming and misread how you were triggering the rollback.)

Your code does the following:

1. Loads all tickets
2. Configures the response format
3. Sets the flash message to Success
4. Performs some record updates

At some point after this, an export error might be raised; this triggers the rollback of the DB transaction, but the `flash[:success]` assignment isn't going to roll back because it's not a DB transaction. Why not try doing a `flash[:error]` rescue block instead of success? Or maybe moving success after yield in the transaction block might work?

Comment: thanks. If I move the flash after the yeild, it is only displayed after I reload the page for some reason. How would I go about doing a flash rescue block?

Comment: also, putting an ensure with a `redirect_to` inside the `wrap_in_transaction` method renders a "too many redirects" error, despite that it is the only one as I see it. So, I'm more confused.

Comment: I used `.discard` on the success flash message inside the `rescue` block to fix the first issue. I still haven't managed to figure out a way to display the flash message without making a redirect_to.

Comment: You probably need some variation on `redirect_to some_path && return` to ensure it stops execution and redirects to the desired path, but I also am not sure that it's even necessary to specify the redirect there given that it looks like you're redirecting to your index path (what happens when you remove the redirect altogether?).